# How to get max of the rows above in each group(Sql or SAS)

Tags: sql, sas, max, teradata

Data:

```
ID   step order 
100  1    1
100  2    2
100  3    3
100  1    4
200  2    5
200  3    6
200  1    7
```

Desired Result( I want to get the max of the rows above in each group)

```
ID   step  max_step
100  1     1
100  2     2
100  3     3
100  1     3
200  2     2
200  3     3
200  1     3
```

Thank you very much!:)

Comment: What database and what version?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, it's in Teradata.

Comment: You cannot do what you want in SQL.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, without a column to determine the ordering there is no concept of the rows above.  In SAS, you can use a data step with `retain`.

Comment: You are right, I missed a column 'order', which means the order of this line of data enter the database. I have edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have some idea of row order, then SAS is going to be the easier answer here.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by ID;
  retain max_step;
  if first.id then call missing(max_step);
  max_step = max(step,max_step);
run;
```

Comment: Great Thanks! This is exactly what I want! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports windowed aggregate then

```
SELECT id,
       step,
       Max(step) OVER( partition BY ID ORDER BY "order") as max_step
From yourtable
```

If you want to max step from above rows irrespective of `ID` then remove the `partition by`

```
SELECT id,
       step,
       Max(step) OVER(ORDER BY "order") as max_step
From yourtable
```

Comment: I tried this. But it seems can only get the max of each group. I want to get the max of the rows above(including the present row) in each group.

Comment: @Sylvia - But in your expected result it is not the case. For `ID = 2`  in `max_step` you have `2` even though previous record has `3`.

Comment: @Prdp It resets with new ID.  But the first row of `id=2` needs to have a `2`.

Comment: Maybe my description is not clear enough. Max is by different id. So previous record in 'ID=100' has nothing to do with the max in 'ID=200'. Joe  is answer is helpful.

Comment: @Sylvia - That is what my first query is doing exactly

Comment: @Prdp you probably need to add a "rows between unbounded preceding and current row" to consider the order in the max (I'm not in front of the computer,  so I cannot check)

Answer (score 0):

You need a *Cumulative Max*:

```
max(step)
over(partition by id
     order by ordercol
     rows unbounded preceding)
```

As Teradata doesn't follow Standard SQL which defaults to `range unbounded preceding` you need to add it (which it's recommended anyway).

Only `last_value` defaults to *cumulative*:

```
last_value(step)
over(partition by id
     order by ordercol)
```

Of course you could add `rows unbounded preceding`, too.